# Calling a ASP.net WebMethod from the success function of another WebMethod

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-services

I have been trying to find a solution to this issue for some time now and would greatly appreciate any help you could offer. I am not looking for an answer using Ajax. Thanks.

The situation I have is one where I need to call a WebMethod that returns an integer. This integer is then displayed to the user in a confirm message. If they confirm then I need to call a second WebMethod and then alert them of the result via an alert message.

When I do this, everything works fine except for the second success function. That function is never reached, and the user is never alerted as a result.

This is example JavaScript of my situation:

```
$( "a" ).live( "click", function() {
    PageMethod.GetCount(OnSucceed, OnFail);
});

OnSucceed(result)
{
    var retVal = Confirm(result);

    if(retVal == false)
        return false;

    PageMethod.Create(Succ, OnFail); //Produces the correct files
}

function Succ(resultStr)
{
    alert(resultStr); //This is never reached
}

function OnFail(error)
{
    alert(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try Closure :
$( "a" ).live( "click", function() {
    PageMethod.GetCount(OnSucceed, OnFail);
});

OnSucceed(result)
{
    var retVal = Confirm(result);

    if(retVal == false)
        return false;

    PageMethod.Create(function(response) { 
     alert(response); 
    }, OnFail); //Produces the correct files
}

function OnFail(error)
{
    alert(error);
}
```

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately the alert is still never reached.  Thanks though!